# How can I stop the background screen is moving to another screen while alert box appears?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, emulation, flutter-alertdialog

I'm using 4 images in each screen. By setting the timer I can see the screen changing within 4 seconds automatically. In each screen below I have given a button for alter dialog box.
When I click on button it will show the alert dialog box, the background images screen is moving to another screen. I want to stop background screen when dialog box appears.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Yeah shared the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel your timer when alert appears.
If you cant reference to it inside here:

```
 onHomeButtonClick: () {
   _showcontent();// method for altert dailog box                                                                                     
                        },
```

You can pass a variable like `var shouldContinue = True` somewhere before and switch it to false when button is clicked